# Web2py server access control to a directory

Tags: apache, web2py

This may not be only a web2py question, but I tried some suggested methods(https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59624/allowing-access-to-an-apache-virtual-host-from-the-local-network-only) in configuring default.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available by adding a new directory to the VirtualHost, I don't know if my config file is wrong or I am doing it in the wrong file or web2py has a simpler way of handling this.
The problem is that even with this code, app2 can be still accessed from non local IPs.

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
 WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www-data/web2py/wsgihandler.py
  WSGIPassAuthorization On
  <Directory /home/www-data/web2py/applications/app1>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
  <Directory /home/www-data/web2py/applications/app2>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 192.168
    Allow from 10
    Satisfy Any
  </Directory>
  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(?:_[\d]+.[\d]+.[\d]+/)?(.*) \
        /home/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2
  <Directory /home/www-data/web2py/applications/*/static/>
    Options -Indexes
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
Require all granted
  </Directory>
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier with some errors and maybe a question?

Comment: I edited the question, the problem is that with this code app2 still can be accessed from non-local IPs. I want app1 to be accessed from any IP but app2 only from local IPs.